# Return SimpleXMLElement element with specific ID attribute?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm creating a SimpleXMLElement object from an XML file:

```
$pages = new SimpleXMLElement('content.xml', LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);
```

A simplified verison of content.xml looks like this: http://pastebin.com/mtvrPAK4

Is there some PHP function that will return the descendent of `$pages` bearing the attribute *id="whatis"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`SimpleXML::xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$pages->xpath('/pages/page[@id = "whatis"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to select XML nodes, the answer is always XPath.

The `SimpleXMLElement` interface to XPath is the `xpath` method.

This will select all elements with an id attribute = 'whatis':

```
$pages->xpath('//*[@id="whatis"]');
```